# Emergency freezing solution for SSD and still have to keep things running?

Tags: ssd, temperature

My SSD OCZ Agility 2 is firing up my x60s laptop, making development in it totally impossible -- it cannot access directories after a while, a lot of nasty lag due to hot temperature! I am now waiting for Intel 320 (bought it because it consumes less energy in idle time according to statistics on this [site](http://www.tomshardware.com/charts/ssd-charts-2011/Power-Requirement-at-Idle,2813.html), trying to find the charts) and a new HDD to replace the SSDs altogether. Some ideas:

- Perhaps SSD out of the laptop to some rack and later full-image-copy to my new same-sized proper SSD or HDD?
- If it is separate, it could be frozen more easily, to make SSD fly. Ideas?

I am currently using all possible fans (about 3 extra fans is all possible extra places such as PCI hole and ordering even more to keep up the development but it is now getting slower. I need run outside to slow down the comp. How can I emergency-freezy my SSD and still keep development going? Even nitrogen -based solutions welcome if they work and easy to accomplish.

Comment: An SSD overheating into uselessness seems to indicate other issues as well. Can you try running the system off a USB stick or livecd  to see if it still overheats, and try the SSD on another system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to develop a new fan control. I did it for my laptop because I've exactly the same problem and I've also add extra cooler like extra cooper cooling and extra laptop cooler. When I replace the OS with Linux or W7 the fan didn't work properly so I was forced to write my own kernel driver in W7 and kernel module in Linux. It's quite easy if you know the register of the embedded controller. In Windows I used the RW everywhere tool to dump and modify the ec. For Linux there is a script for acer laptops that can dump and control the ec written in perl and hosted at google.